# Range Slider Styles (IE 11)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

Does anyone know what these black lines are called (don't appear to be ticks) and how to target them (if possible) with css?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
    input[type=range]::-ms-track { 
        color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
```